# How to get the current URL in a Confluence Macro?

Tags: velocity, confluence

I am using Confluence and I am trying to build a User Macro (using Velocity). I would need a way to obtain the current page URL and use it as a variable. I need the whole URL (ex: http://confluence.idi.local/display/~mircea/Testing+Macros). Is there a way to achieve this? Been looking for 2 days now and I couldn't find anything...

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it:

```
$action.getGlobalSettings().getBaseUrl()$content.getUrlPath()
```

This will display the complete URL of the page where the macro is executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you not just want the configured base url, you can also use the HttpServletRequest in the execute method, as described here:
[How do I get hold of the HttpServletRequest?](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/development-resources/confluence-developer-faq/how-do-i-get-hold-of-the-httpservletrequest)